# How to validate TLS version from application client, not server

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, tls1.2

We are trying to validate what TLS version our web client application is using. We can run `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.example.com` as we see TLS version 1.2 (That's the version we want.) However we are wanting to validate what version of TLS is being used from web application client directly? Not the server. This is a 1.6 java application that is deployed on Weblogic. Is this request possible to validate on the application directly? I see a lot of threads validating at the server level or the or validating what the server end, not the client application level.

Comment: Do a single packet capture with Wireshark  of the client connecting to the server and check the ClientHello message from the client. It contains the best TLS protocol version the client supports and all ciphers.

Comment: I'll have to investigate how to use WireShark to intercept that call and check it's diagnostics for what it finds. Thank you @SteffenUllrich